# Error installing LDAP Browser plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ldap

I have installed eclipse jee juno in my linux 12.10 environment and I tried to install the LDAP Browser plugin using install new Software option. But it gives me the following error. How can I solve this?

```
    An error occurred while installing the items
`session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,` phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.apache.commons.io 2.4.0, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]org.apache.commons.io 2.4.0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install you need to add this in Eclipse:

http://directory.apache.org/studio/update/2.x

After that select:

The Apache Directory Studio Browser

Comment: you have java 6? and Eclipse 3.3? (requires)

Comment: There was something wrong in my eclipse installation. So I removed and re installed. Then It Worked.

Comment: Saw same behavior with Eclipse 4.2 when trying to install all components of Apache Directory Studio Browser. Deleted the Eclipse install, installed just LDAP Browser, and it completed successfully.